# sed - what's wrong with my replacement?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a list of 300+ files that have to be edited, so i thought that sed command in tandem with find and exec could help me.

Before doing something wrong (like overwrite files that I won't modify, or something like that) I decided to use sed and output his result into bash instead local substitution.

The string i'm searchin' for is: `<tr><td class="button" style=" background:#040404; color:#eee9dc; font-size: 23px; padding:5px 0; text-align:center;"><a href="../Z2/C24357-0/hhcm-LASTMINUTES.html" style=" text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer; color:#eee9dc">Offerte & LastMinute</a></td></tr>`

and I only want to replace that part `<a href="../Z2/C24357-0/hhcm-LASTMINUTES.html` with `<a href="../../../special_offers.php?lang=it"`

Since I'm a noob about `regex` , i'll take a look at that [web page](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#intro) that drive me into regex argument in a decent way.

Now, i've try something like that (on a single file, just for take a look to the output in a "safe" way)

```
 sed s/\<a.*LAST.*html\"
      /\<a href="\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\/special_offers\.php\?lang=en"/ 
      C25030-9_3/hhcm-Solo_per_due.html
```

and I get that error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated s' command`
like the `sed` expressions isn't correct, but I don't know if the error is into the `replacement` part or somewhere else.

Thanks from now for your time and effort.

S.

**Edit**

Thanks to answers, I resolved it by doin' something this

```
sed 's/<a.*LAST.*html\"/\<a href="..\/..\/..\/special_offers.php?lang=en"/' C25030-9_3/hhcm-Solo_per_due.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems that you need to put the whole sed expression (`s/.../.../`) in single quotes, second, you forgot the `/` in the end *(see edit)*, and third, don't forget that the substitution will only work if the whole pattern string is on one line.

EDIT: More info on `s` command ([see here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1), for example): it's `s/old/new/` and possible flags after the last `/`. Your command looks like `s/something/somethingelse/somethingelse`, it has more than it should, I think.

Comment: For single line part, yes thank you, but i just make it in that way for make it more readable for s.o. users. Where i've missing it? I see it after `"` char

Comment: Funny, I didn't get that the last part (`C25030-9_3/hhcm-Solo_per_due.html`) was actually the name of the input file. But neither did `sed` (because of the lack of quotes), and that was the problem.